# Creating categories of one column based on the categories of another in R

Tags: r, grouping, categories

So I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
           x   y
1      (0,4]   1
2      (0,4]   2
3      (0,4]   3
4      (0,4]   4
5      (4,5]   5
6     (5,10]   6
7     (5,10]   7
8     (5,10]   8
9     (5,10]   9
10    (5,10]  10
11   (10,20]  11
12   (10,20]  12
13   (10,20]  13
14   (10,20]  14
15   (10,20]  15
16   (10,20]  16
17   (10,20]  17
18   (10,20]  18
19   (10,20]  19
20   (10,20]  20
21   (20,40]  21
22   (20,40]  22
23   (20,40]  23
24   (20,40]  24
25   (20,40]  25
26   (20,40]  26
27   (20,40]  27
28   (20,40]  28
29   (20,40]  29
30   (20,40]  30
```

And I want to partition the Y column by the irregular partitions that have categorised the x column, without going through and hard coding each specific cut off point. Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Edit: hoped for output

```
         x       y
1    (0,4]   (0,4]
2    (0,4]   (0,4]
3    (0,4]   (0,4]
4    (0,4]   (0,4]
5    (4,5]   (4,5]
6   (5,10]  (5,10]
7   (5,10]  (5,10]
8   (5,10]  (5,10]
9   (5,10]  (5,10]
10  (5,10]  (5,10]
11 (10,20] (10,20]
12 (10,20] (10,20]
13 (10,20] (10,20]
14 (10,20] (10,20]
15 (10,20] (10,20]
16 (10,20] (10,20]
17 (10,20] (10,20]
18 (10,20] (10,20]
19 (10,20] (10,20]
20 (10,20] (10,20]
21 (20,40] (20,40]
22 (20,40] (20,40]
23 (20,40] (20,40]
24 (20,40] (20,40]
25 (20,40] (20,40]
26 (20,40] (20,40]
27 (20,40] (20,40]
28 (20,40] (20,40]
29 (20,40] (20,40]
30 (20,40] (20,40]
```

Comment: @akrun I feel like you have told me off for this before. Apologies for forgetting to put the output again. I will edit now.

Comment: Your output seems to show two identical columns.... `data.frame(x = df$x, y = df$x)`

Comment: You can try `df1$y <- df1$x`

Comment: @Frank that's because I am dealing with two columns which, when categorised, would look identical.

Comment: Use the same code that partitioned `x` to partition `y`.

Comment: @akrun that would replace y with x when I just need to cuts applied to x to be applied to y.

Comment: Then use `?cut` i.e. `cut(df1$y, breaks =c(0,4, 5,10, 20, 40))`

Comment: @gregor sadly the original partitions code is not available to me and the actual data frame I am using is much larger than this example meaning I cant go through each partition and note where the cuts are made.

Comment: @akrun see my reply to gregor for the issues with your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract numbers from existing cutpoints:

```
library(stringr)
cutpoints = sort(as.numeric(unique(unlist(str_extract_all(df$x, pattern = "\\d+")))))
```

Cut using these cutpoints

```
df$y = cut(df$y, breaks = cutpoints)
```

Using this reproducible data:

```
df = structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("(0,4]", "(10,20]", "(20,40]", 
"(4,5]", "(5,10]"), class = "factor"), y = 1:30), .Names = c("x", 
"y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "30"))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can extract the last numeric substring from 'x', convert to `numeric`, get the `unique` elements and use it as `breaks` in the `cut`

```
 cut(df1$y, breaks= c(0,sort(unique(as.numeric(sub(".*,(\\d+)\\D+$", "\\1", df1$x))))))
 #[1] (0,4]   (0,4]   (0,4]   (0,4]   (4,5]   (5,10]  (5,10]  (5,10]  (5,10] 
 #[10] (5,10]  (10,20] (10,20] (10,20] (10,20] (10,20] (10,20] (10,20] (10,20]
 #[19] (10,20] (10,20] (20,40] (20,40] (20,40] (20,40] (20,40] (20,40] (20,40]
 #[28] (20,40] (20,40] (20,40]
 #Levels: (0,4] (4,5] (5,10] (10,20] (20,40]
```